# VWD 2013 - Outlining JavaScript object literals

Tags: javascript, vwdexpress

I am making a website in Visual Studio Web Developer **Express** 2013, and I have a JavaScript object literal.  It looks something like this:

```
var myObj = {
  a: function(x) {...},
  b: function(x) {...},
  c: function(x) {...},
}
```

Visual Studio's outliner allows me to collapse the functions (`a`, `b`, and `c`), but it does not let me collapse the object literal itself (`myObj`).  This is rather annoying because I have a much larger object literal and I would like to collapse it.  Is there any solution for VWD 2013 that works for the express version?

Answer (score 0):

This VS 2010/2013 [extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4be701d8-af03-40a4-8cdc-d2add5cde46c) solves the issue.

Comment: I tried installing it and it gave me a "This extension is not installable with any current products" error.  Not sure if it's not updated to 2013.3 or if it doesn't support Express.